# How would I make a Twitter-like feed using SQL/PHP?

Tags: php, sql, feed

On the site I am building, users can follow others and post things. I am trying to compile a feed page that allows users to see all the posts in chronological order from people they follow (pretty much what Twitter does).

The SQL table for holding "posts" (entitled "posts") is set up with the columns:

- "id" (autoincremented)
- "material" (text content of post)
- "whencreated" (when posted)
- "authorid" (user that posted it)

The SQL table for holding following/followers (entitled "follow") contains the columns:

- "id"(autoincremented)
- "followerid" (id of follower)
- "followingid" (id of who they are following)

I essentially need to know how to loop through a person's "following" ids and list out the posts by each following id in chronological order. Once again, the result is pretty much a clone of Twitter.

Thanks! Sorry if this is too specific.

Comment: You can use the preview window whilst you're typing to see how a question will come out, and if you spot a problem, just hit the 'edit' link above.

Comment: As for the question, in general it is a good idea to show what you've tried first. This helps the (very busy) community choose between people who really want to make an effort (I think you're one of those) and people who aren't willing to (so-called "help vampires"). So, you'll need a `SELECT` query with a `JOIN`, and some PHP (perhaps using MySQL and PDO) to run it. Can you give it a bash?

Comment: A good helpful hint is _break problems down_. I'd create the database first, then insert some test data, then work out how to run a query in PDO, then work out how to do a join, and then you're 80% of the way there.

Comment: Thanks halfer... I'll give it a try :) Usually I do solve my own problems, but today was a LONG day and didn't even know where to start with this one. I'll try what you told me with JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts
INNER JOIN follow ON posts.authorid = follow.followingid
WHERE follow.followerid = ?
ORDER BY posts.whencreated DESC
```

Where `?` is the ID of the current user.

I suggest you to have a look at these info pages about [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) and [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

This is only the SQL part, I'm going to leave the PHP part as an exercise.